# Converting generic redis code to Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: spring-session, lettuce, azure-redis-cache

I have the following Spring Session code:

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    String hostName = AcmeProperty.getProperty("spring.redis.host", "localhost");
    int port = Integer.parseInt(AcmeProperty.getProperty("spring.redis.port", "6379"));
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(hostName, port);

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}
```

It works just fine with the following settings when I'm running redis locally:

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

However when I use Azure Cache for Redis with the following setting:

```
spring.redis.host=acmedev.redis.cache.windows.net
spring.redis.port=6380
```

I get this warning and the app hangs:

```
WARN (org.springframework.session.config.annotation.web.http.SpringHttpSessionConfiguration:166) || - Unable to obtain SessionCookieConfig: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
```

What do I need to change to get this to work with Azure Cache for Redis?

I've tried [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-remove-tls-10-11), but the same thing happens:

```
@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    String hostName = AcmeProperty.getProperty("spring.redis.host", "localhost");
    int port = Integer.parseInt(AcmeProperty.getProperty("spring.redis.port", "6379"));
    String password = AcmeProperty.getProperty("spring.redis.password");

    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLParameters sslParameters = new SSLParameters();
    sslParameters.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");
    sslParameters.setProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});

    String uriStr = String.format("rediss://%s:%s", hostName, port);
    URI uri = URI.create(uriStr);
    JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo(uri, sslSocketFactory, sslParameters, null);

    shardInfo.setPassword(password);

    return new JedisConnectionFactory(shardInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an XML Spring configuration; a Java configuration won't work.  See ["Unable to obtain SessionCookieConfig"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1040).

```
<util:constant id="configureRedisAction"
               static-field="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"
      p:configureRedisAction-ref="configureRedisAction"/>

<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxTotal" value="200" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="50" />
    <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="30000" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${spring.redis.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${spring.redis.port}" />
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
    <property name="usePool" value="true" />
    <property name="useSsl" value="${spring.redis.ssl}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${spring.redis.password}"/>
</bean>
```